# How to compare these two datasets?

Tags: r

I have two datasets:

First Dataset -

```
     A  B  C  D  E  F
Cat  1  0  1  0  0  1
Dog  0  1  1  0  0  0
Fish 1  1  1  1  0  0
Frog 0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Second Dataset

```
      A    B   C    D    E     F
Cat  2.3  1.4  3.6  7.2  1.3  1.2
Dog  1.2  1.7  1.9  2.3  4.5  6.3
Fish 1.1  1.2  2.4  3.6  3.8  0.2
Frog 1.5  1.9  2.3  5.4  2.3  4.5
```

How do make a new matrix/dataset so that all the ones in the first dataset becomes the value in the second dataset, and all the zeros in dataset one stay the same. For example, I want to combine the first and second dataset I just made into:

```
    |  A  | B   |  C  | D   |  E |  F  |
----|-----|-----|-----|-----|----|-----|
Cat | 2.3 | 0   | 3.6 |  0  |  0 | 1.2 |
----|---- |-----|-----|-----|----|-----|
Dog | 0   |1.7  | 1.9 |  0  |  0 |  0  |
----|-----|-----|-----|-----|----|-----|
Fish| 1.1 |1.2  | 2.4 | 3.6 |  0 |  0  |
----|-----|-----|-----|-----|----|-----|        
Frog| 0   | 0   |  0  |  0  |  0 | 4.5 |
```

Answer (score 6):

No need to transform to a matrix:

```
 > df1*df2 
       A   B   C   D E   F
Cat  2.3 0.0 3.6 0.0 0 1.2
Dog  0.0 1.7 1.9 0.0 0 0.0
Fish 1.1 1.2 2.4 3.6 0 0.0
Frog 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0 4.5
```

Comment: You can multiply data frames!  Who knew?!?